# Complex Fourier series of $1-t$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

I'm trying to compute the complex Fourier series of the function $f(t)$ which is defined as $$f (t) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
1-t & t \in  [0,1] \\
0 & \,t \in  [1,2] \\
\end{array}
\right. $$
. Since $f(t)$ has a period of $2$ and I can compute the complex coefficient $c_n = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1(1-t)e^{-in\pi t}dt$ but this gets me into integration by parts and results in a coefficient $c_n=-\frac{-1 + e^{-i n π} + i n π}{n^2 π^2}$ which seems unfitting in scope in the context of the other tasks that I'm doing which is why I have a feeling that I am making a mistake. Can anybody tell me if I am on the right track?

Comment: your formula can't be correct for $n=0$, but also why do yo u think its wrong

Comment: Before it was just gut feeling, but now that you pointed it out obviously because the coefficient doesn't exist for division through $n=0$, I forgot that in exponential form the sum goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. Could help me find where I'm going wrong?

Comment: for $n=0$ its just a normal integral which is $c_0=1/4$

Comment: Thanks, but how did you get to that? And how does it help me understand where my approach is wrong?

Comment: your approach isn't wrong for $n\neq 0$, for $n=0$ your formula isn't correct and it couldn't be correct from the division by 0 as you noticed, you just compute the integral differently. the answer doesn't seem immediately wrong to me, how are you testing if its wrong?